# Why "play run" doesn't read my configuration file?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm using `"play run"` when I implement something on Play Framework because it supports auto-compile feature.  But it seems that `"play run"` doesn't read configuration file that I specify.  I'm running Play Framework as follows:

```
$ play "run -Dconfig.resource=application.conf"
```

But configurations written on application.conf are totally ignored.  If I do `"play start"` instead, the configuration file works fine.  Is there any way to specify configuration file with `"play run"`?

I'm using Play Framework 2.1.1 on MacOS 10.8.3.

Comment: Does [this](http://afartinspace.com/post/28977419765/play-multiple-environments) (using `config.file` instead of `config.resource`) help?

Comment: Thanks! `config.file` works fine with dev mode!

Comment: @Carsten, place an answer pls, so the question will be possible to mark as answered.solved

Comment: @biesior Yeah, I was actually trying to avoid digging around in order to find the piece of code where this option is parsed. Now you've kinda forced me to do it. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Play doesn't seem to listen to the configuration option `config.resource`. A quick Google search led to [this blog post](http://afartinspace.com/post/28977419765/play-multiple-environments), which suggested to use `config.file` instead. The value here would be a file name, relative to your Play application's root directory.

Well, to create a proper answer, I had to research how you could change the main configuration file. What I've found is that [Play checks for the `config.file` property, and if it doesn't exist, uses `conf/application.conf`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/ac233158fffcdcc35d9906436ab414f7515fd620/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L33).

Therefore, the way to run it with a custom configuration file is

```
play "run -Dconfig.file=application.conf"
```

Your can either provide a file path relative to your Play application's root directory or an absolute path.

Comment: Very helpful! I had to run the following to get it to work for me:

play "run -Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf"

Comment: Cant believe I just miss two quotes. Thanks